# Re(z) is an open map

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, open-map

Is there an explicit way to show this using theorems in real/complex analysis, without using topology?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2625813/proving-that-p-mathbbc-rightarrow-mathbbr-defined-by-pz-rez-is-ope

Comment: Openness of sets itself is a topological property. How can we not involve topology here?

Comment: What is your definition of open map and open set? As Clement Yung points out, these are topological notions used in real/complex analysis. It would help to know precisely what definitions you use, so we can stay within what you're familiar with.

Comment: I meant in a way that the proof only can use the standard topology in R and C, like open and closed defined in terms of open balls and boundaries, etc

Answer (score 2):

Well obviously some topological notions are necessary; but a quick way to get at this is note that holomorphic functions $f(z)$ are open maps (the open mappig theorem), and the projection $\pi_{\Bbb R}$ onto the real axis is open [(see this wikipedia page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps), so

$\Re(f) = \pi_{\Bbb R} \circ f \tag 1$

is open.

As pointed out by users 797616 Trash Failure in their comments to this answer, there is no need to invoke the openness of general holomorphic $f(z)$  since all that is asked for is the openness of $\Re(z)$; my enthusiasm for generalization got the better of me.

Comment: @user797616:  don't you need $f(z)$ open?

Comment: There is no f involved.

Comment: @user797616:  oh yeah you are right!  Misread the question, will edit answer.

Comment: Fro Wikipedia, the justification is “ Since the projections of fiber bundles and covering maps are locally natural projections of products, these are also open maps.” I was wondering there is proof of my question that uses techniques in standard real/complex analysis

Comment: @TrashFailure The real part mapping is projection onto first factor, as mentioned here. The fact that this is an open map can be very easily verified using definitions. Let $U \subset \Bbb{C} = \Bbb{R}^2$ be open, we have to show $\pi_1[U]$ is open. This is simple. For each $p\in U$, we can find an open rectangle $R_p = A_p \times B_p$  (by which I mean $A_p, B_p \subset \Bbb{R}$ are open intervals) such that $p \in R_p \subset U_p$. Now, it is clear that $\pi_1[U] = \bigcup_{p \in U} \pi_1[R_p] = \bigcup_{p \in U} A_p$, which is a union of open sets in $\Bbb{R}$, and hence open.

Comment: Can we just say $\mathbb C = \mathbb R^2$?

Comment: How do you justify that the projection and union commute?

Comment: @TrashFailure:  that is proved in the wikipedia article I cited/linked.